# Non-linear Dirichlet problem with FD

Tags: optimization, discrete-optimization

I face to the following problem:

$$(1+u_x^2)u_{yy} - 2u_xu_yu_{xy} + (1+u_y^2)u_{xx}=0.$$ It should be discretized by finite differences.

Does anybody know, how to proceed? Or does anybody know about any book/ reference in order to understand problem better ?

Every suggestion is welcomed! Thanks!

Comment: Differential equation definition: A surface M ⊂ R3 is minimal if and only if it can be locally expressed as the graph of a solution of

        (1+u_x^2)u_{yy} - 2u_xu_yu_{xy} + (1+u_y^2)u_{xx}=0

The partial differential equation in this definition was originally found in 1762 by Lagrange,[2] and Jean Baptiste Meusnier discovered in 1776 that it implied a vanishing mean curvature.[3]  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_surface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first attempt to solve the problem using standard finite difference method. You can find several books on finite difference technique and online documents. For example take a look at [**this document**](http://laplace.physics.ubc.ca/People/matt/Teaching/06Mexico/mexico06.pdf)) Particularly section 2 describes what you need.

The standard procedure for non-linear PDEs is to use iterative schemes, first you can discretize the equation, then proceed with a **Gauss-Seidel relaxation** to see if it converge. This process is the same as solving Poisson equation, but you implement an iterative algorithm that can also apply for non-linear problems.

There is a pretty good chance that Gauss-Seidel will converge and you'd get your solution. If not you can attempt a technique called **continuation method** where you first create a solver that can effectively solve a linear problem, in your case, lets write your equation as:
$$
(1+\alpha u_x^2)u_{yy}  -2 \beta u_x u_y u_{xy} + (1+\alpha u_y^2)u_{xx} = 0 
$$ 
Where, $\alpha =1$ and $\beta = 1$ is your equation. As you can see, setting: $\alpha = 0$ and $\beta = 0$ the equation reduces to a linear Poisson equation. Therefore your iterative solver can first solve the linear solution (which shouldn't be a problem) then have that solution of the linear problem as a good initial guess for a new problem where you can choose a small (non-zero now) value for $\alpha$ and $\beta$, let's say $\alpha = 0.1$ and $\beta = 0.1$ therefore, now you have a PDE that is slightly different than linear problem, and the solver will have a much better chance to converge, after solving that problem, you can use that solution as an initial guess for a new problem where now $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are even higher, say $\alpha=0.2$ and $\beta = 0.2$, so as you can see by "continuation" you approach to your desired problem and your solver should be able to converge during this continuous process.

There is also a [**finite difference toolkit**](http://laplace.phas.ubc.ca/People/arman/FD_doc/) available  (written in Maple programming language) that you can use. See the user manual and tutorials section.
It provides all the tools you need to implement a Newton-Gauss-Seidel relaxation routine, assuming that you are familiar with programming in C and Fortran, and also somewhat familiar with Maple software.

In some cases that the non-linear problem is very hard to deal with (which I doubt your equation would be such case) then you need to implement more advanced algorithm such as **Pseudo-Spectral method**

Comment: many thanks for your answer! However, after discretization, my equation should be solved in trust region framework. I have no idea how to proceed in such a direction. Would you have any ideas?